# Fortran: pointer procedure to a subroutine in a parent module

Tags: pointers, fortran

I stumbled with a way to run in a child module a procedure of the father. I mean, the trick allow me to run a process in a upstream way, in relation with the dependencies tree of the modules. In concrete, here is the example:

```
module parent
  procedure(likefoo),pointer :: to_foo
  interface 
    subroutine likefoo
    end subroutine likefoo
  end interface
contains
  subroutine run
   call to_foo
  end subroutine
end module 

module child
  use parent
contains
  subroutine foo
      print *, 'hola'
  end subroutine foo
end module 

program main
  use parent
  use child

  to_foo => foo
  call run

end program
```

This example was positive tested with ifort 13.0.0. 
I wonder, This code is allowed by the standard or just it run ok because is a compiler dependence feature?. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is fine (using F2003 features), but make the interface for likefoo abstract.  The requirement for a directed graph of module dependence is an orthogonal concept to the nesting of calls to procedures in those modules.

Comment: Thanks!, Can you explain a little more about the two concepts? Thank you again

Comment: It means that you are not really running a procedure "in" the child module. You just have both the `child` and `father` modules in the scope of your main program, so you can assign the procedure pointer to any accessible procedure that matches its interface, including in this case `foo`. The `use parent` in the child module is not actually necessary for this. Also note that, while this will compile, `to_foo` may not be associated when you call `run`, giving a segfault. You can check this status with `associated(to_foo)`.